# Change permissions for multiple files at once on OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, permissions

I moved thousands of images from iPhoto to another user account, and now I don't have permission to view some of the images.

So, I ask: Is there a way change the permissions for multiple files on OS X 10.6.8 instead of one by one?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. You can do that using simple terminal commands. For example if you want to change the permission of all files in photo folder that ends in .jpg, go to applications-->utilities--->Terminal and type

```
chmod 777 /Users/$home/Photos/*.jpg
```

or to do all files in the folder, type

```
chmod 777 /Users/$home/Photos/*
```

Answer (score 3):

The proper command is

```
sudo chown $USER -R $HOME/Photos/*
```

chown means "CHange OWNership", you will need to type your password to allow the command to succeed. Run the command in the Terminal.app.